# Shopify GraphQL Storefront API Query Error

Tags: json, api, next.js, graphql, shopify

Hello I am a beginner with GrapQL/Shopify and have been following the documentation [here](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/2023-01/queries/collection). After trying to run a basic Storefront API call below to get information about a Collection

```
query getProductById($id: "gid://shopify/Product/xxxxxxxxx") {
  product(id: $id) {
    title
  }
}
```

I get the error below

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Parse error on \"gid://shopify/Product/xxxxxxxxx\" (STRING) at [1, 27]",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 27
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm sure it's a syntax issue but the documentation isn't very clear on what the correct way of entering the query argument information is.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing the data type of the product ID where you're currently passing the product ID. In this case, the data type of the product ID is `ID!`

It should look like this:

```
query getProductById($id: ID!) {
  product(id: $id) {
    title
  }
}
```

The product ID is sent in the `variables` object which is separate to the query

Shopify have a really useful GraphQL tool to help get a better understanding of how to query data from your store
https://shopify-graphiql-app.shopifycloud.com/login

Comment: Thanks for this information @Nathan. The shopify-graphiql-app is very helpful.